# SSIS 2012 and SSIS farm

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I tried to find an answer on many forums but couldn't find something which will work in my environment.

I just moved to a new company where I would be working on rewriting many of the ETL feeds. As of now, we have few 2008 packages and a few 2012 packages deployed on a regular file system as dtsx files and invoked from Automic/ UC4. In prod environment, we have two SSIS servers (load balanced by the UC4 client)

My plan is to upgrade to the package deployment model and host all the packages as a project on the SSIS server.

The concern/ question I have is the deployment/ execution part. Should I deploy to both the SSIS servers?

-> From what DBAs are saying, MS recommendation was not to use cluster for SSIS installation (I assume thats why they were using two SSIS servers and load balanced from UC4)

-> If I deploy to both the servers, it would duplicate the deployment process. That would also mean I have to do all the configuration twice.

-> If the packages are running from either of the servers, corresponding logs are also stored in either of the servers. If I have to use a tool for reporting, it may not be a good option.

Has anyone else faced this situation? 
Any one using SSIS farm architecture like ours, and also using package deployment model?

Regards,

Nayak

Comment: my advice would be: try to avoid using SSIS if at all possible. It's great for fast table loads, but when it breaks it's a PITA

Comment: I know. Usual approach would be to do few things within the SQL Server when it makes sense. But there are a few things like loading data which need an ETL setup. One more reason I think is to offload some of the load on the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS is not cluster aware. When utilizing any solution, package or project deployment model, the packages should be deployed to each server in the cluster.

[MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-ssis-in-a-cluster)

You then need a way to identify which node to use in the case of a failover cluster. I have used a few solutions to this in the past, most recently using always on, id have an agent job on both machines, but it checks first if its machine is  the primary replica, and if not, it does nothing.

Your solution may differ as you have an external load balancer but unless the packages are designed to run from both machines you will need a way to identify the primary node.

Comment: Thanks, Wilson. MSDN link was helpful.